# How can I take an injected dll and export it as its own dll file?

Tags: dll, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to take a dll which, upon injecting itself, will unpack itself, however when inactive will stay packed with no real needed information. How can I take the dll after it has been injected into a process and extract it? I've tried searching online for answers, however I cant seem to find anything recent and related to my question. If you have any questions feel free to ask, as well as feel free to tell me how I can improve my question. Thanks!

Comment: What's a packed dll?

Comment: @ssbssa basically its normal commands like mov arent visible until it's injected into something, once its injected all of those commands become visible, i.e. unpacking the dll.

Comment: It depends how it was injected, if the injector used LoadLibrary you can just dump every module for example with Scylla